# What is the variable for Santa's current location in the Google Santa Tracking Api?

Tags: python

I tried finding Santa's current location, but the location variable only contained my current location. I want to be able to find Santa's current location on the Api, https://santa-api.appspot.com/info?client=web&language=en&fingerprint=&routeOffset=0&streamOffset=0.

I tried using the location variable and I got my current location.

```
import requests
santaApi = requests.get("https://santa-api.appspot.com/info?client=web&language=en&fingerprint=&routeOffset=0&streamOffset=0").json()
formatted_data = santaApi["location"]
print(formatted_data)
```

This is my code and when I ran it I got my current location.

I expected to get Santa's location but I got mine instead.